# Displaying list using UIAlertController take too much time

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I am having a list of countries which i want to show using `UIAlertController`.It does get showed up but it takes too much time as there are about 150+ countries.

So how can i fasten up this process using `UIAlertController` only.

Here is my code :

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Select country", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
let cancel1 = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil)
alert.addAction(cancel1)

for dict in self.aCountry{
  let tempDict:[String:Any] = dict as! [String:Any]
  let action = UIAlertAction.init(title: tempDict["country_name"] as? String, style: .default) { (completed) in
      self.tfCountry.text = tempDict["country_name"] as? String
  }
  alert.addAction(action)
}

let cancel2 = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil)
alert.addAction(cancel2)
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

P.s - `aCountry` is the array of countries names

Comment: did you try action sheet instead of alert style?

Comment: Have you tried running this code on the main thread?

Comment: wouldn't a UIPicker be more useful?

Comment: @AlanS not yet. could you suggest the code to do that

Comment: @TejaNandamuri using action sheet fasten up the process by just 1 second.

Comment: @Scriptable yes, but the UI Interface needs to be exactly like UIAlertController instead of Pickerview or a custom UIViewController.

Comment: You can wrap your code around in between the brackets of this: DispatchQueue.main.async { [Your code here] } . But I just tested this and I had the alert view created in 3.8 seconds without the Main thread and 3.3 seconds with the main thread. So i don't think it'll be much help.

Comment: As others have said, I believe a custom controller is probably better, you could make it into a table view controller quite easily and present it over your current VC, or a UIPicker like others have said.

Comment: @AlanS Thanks. that created a difference

Answer (score 0):

> So how can i fasten up this process using UIAlertController only.

You can't. Use a custom presented UIViewController instead. UIAlertController is not made for this sort of thing. A custom UIViewController will let you use a much better, faster interface. A picker view, as suggested in comments, would be a good interface. If the goal is let the user enter the country in a text field or similar, an even better approach is to use the picker view as the "keyboard" that appears when the user taps in the text field.

Comment: Yes, but the UI Interface needs to be exactly like UIAlertController instead of Pickerview or a custom UIViewController.

Comment: I don't trust claims like "the UI Interface needs to be". However, you are certainly welcome to make a presented view controller that _looks_ like a UIAlertController. I've explained how to do that, here: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7